# glfwCreateWindow producing "MessageTracer: load_domain_whitelist_search_tree" warning

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I tried a very basic program to make a  triangle on OSX 10.13. It is compiling fine except with some warnings like [GLFW first responder error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146121/glfw-first-responder-error) and [Search tree file's format version number (0) is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46463333/what-is-the-meaning-of-search-tree-files-format-version-number-0-is-not-sup) . I was able to remove the first by just compiling GLFW from the Github. However I am unable to get rid of the second error:

```
2018-05-12 15:40:06.765748+0200 OpenGLTestProject[16217:1749829] MessageTracer: load_domain_whitelist_search_tree:73: Search tree file's format version number (0) is not supported
2018-05-12 15:40:06.765807+0200 OpenGLTestProject[16217:1749829] MessageTracer: Falling back to default whitelist
```

I created debug point and the warning appears at this line :

```
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
```