# Mac osx WebView dialog

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, webview

I'm trying to run `WebView` on my `Mac OS X` application.
I'm running `Instagram` page With this code:

```
[self.webView setFrameLoadDelegate:self];
self.webView.customUserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A403 Safari/602.1";

NSString * urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/"];
NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
[[self.webView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
```

The code running great and the application run without any problem.
When I click in `Instagram` on the Plus button to upload new photo nothing is happening and I get this error in the console log:

```
[22222:59575044] MessageTracer: load_domain_whitelist_search_tree:73: Search tree file's format version number (0) is not supported
[22222:59575044] MessageTracer: Falling back to default whitelist
```

Any idea what is this error? Why the file dialog is not popup.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of: "Search tree file's format version number (0) is not supported"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46463333/what-is-the-meaning-of-search-tree-files-format-version-number-0-is-not-sup)